# Potential bug in the .NET Framework VisualTreeHelper class

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I believe to have found a bug in the .NET Framework.

**Summary:**

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application, and tried using the `VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups()` method. As parameter, I used `Window.Current`.

It is unable to find any currently shown popups, made with the `MessageDialog` (even though `MessageDialog` inherits from (`Windows.UI.Popups`).

I am however able to find any popups currently shown, which I have created from the ContentDialog class, so there seems to be a bug here.

Can anyone confirm that there's not something I have fundamentally misunderstood, before I classify it as a bug?

**Example in depth:**

I have two projects running. Which of them is my Windows Phone project, and another is a NUnit project that tests my app.

In my NUnit project, I have code that boils down to:

```
OpenApp(); //Done through Winium which I use for UI testing
OpenPopup; //This works fine, the popup comes.

//Give my root-app window as current window, so it iteratively searches from there.
var popupcount = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.current);
```

If I in my Windows Phone project uses this line of code:

```
var m = new MessageDialog("");
var popupCount = m.ShowAsync();
```

Then the popupcount returned by the VisualTreeHelper is 0 in my NUnit project.

If, however, I use this line of code:

```
var m = new ContentDialog("");
var popupCount = m.ShowAsync();
```

It is not 0.

Comment: Forgetting to await an async method is not a framework bug.  The proper name is "threading race bug".

Comment: My bad. I do call: "await m.showAsync()" In both cases. I just wanted to dumb the code down. The case here is that I have my UWP app running, which is awaiting the result of the popup (thus I use await, so I can wait for the user's answer). In another project, I am UI testing my code, so when the popup is shown, I try to access the popup, so I can click the button in it. However, I am unable to access the popup, since I cannot find the handle to the buttons in the VisualTreeHelper.

Comment: @oPolo You should update your question to show that you're using `async ` and make sure to add every detail possible before the claim of finding a bug in the framework can be taken seriously.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getopenpopups.aspx) can retrieves a collection of all open popup controls from the target **[Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.aspx)**. However `MessageDialog` is not in your `Window`. To see this you can run you code in Windows 10 Mobile Emulator to take advantage of [**Live Visual Tree**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx). Following is the code I used to test:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Margin="50">
    <Button Click="MessageDialog_Click">Show
MessageDialog</Button>
    <Button Margin="0,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ContentDialog_Click">Show ContentDialog</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
private async void MessageDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("MessageDialog Test");

    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}

private async void ContentDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var contentDialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "ContentDialog Test",
        Content = "This is ContentDialog Test",
        PrimaryButtonText = "Ok"
    };

    await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

When you show MessageDialog, there is nothing in [PopupRoot].
[image]

And when you show ContentDialog, it's in [PopupRoot].
[image]

So when you use `VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups` method with `MessageDialog`, the count is 0. But for `ContentDialog`, it's not 0.

In fact, [MessageDialog class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) does not inherits from `Windows.UI.Popups`, it is just in `Windows.UI.Popups` namespace and implements `IMessageDialog` interface. You can use "Go To Definition(F12)" in Visual Studio to find it.
[image]

And [Popup class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842) is in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives` namespace, inherits from [FrameworkElement class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement). They are not relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback!!! That was a _really_ thorough answer, I had not expected that! It makes sense then that the VisualTreeHelper could not find any popups. I also just tried checking after reading your answer, and indeed the top parent of the message dialog XAML element is some root system process on my phone, and not my application. A bit of a weird design-choice though, as it is nearly impossible to unit tests messagedialog-elements then... ContentDialogs will have to do, thanks!